# GCP - Deploy python code and run automatically

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Can anyone suggest or give any link that I can follow for deploying the python code in GCP? My code is the scraping website code then I want to load that data into BigQuery hourly. Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: There are many platforms to choose from when deploying apps to GCP. Could you be more specific about your use case?  I suggest starting out on this blog first https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/where-should-i-run-my-stuff-choosing-google-cloud-compute-option

Comment: its just a script that scrape the website and update to BQ data everyday.. can u suggest what is the best platform with the link that i can follow? @Dondi

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/getting-started/getting-started-on-compute-engine

Comment: What do you want to do? What's your code do? What's your code requirement? too much question!! Add more details!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere already edit the question. is it enough?

Comment: If the scrape takes less than 30 minutes, you can use Cloud Run to deploy your code and Cloud Scheduler to trigger Cloud Run. you can find example/tutorial on Google Cloud documentation

Comment: Thanks for the respond! Appreciate if i can get the docs bcs i dont find any docs that help me for this. @guillaumeblaquiere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy Python web scraper by following this guide. This guide uses Cloud Functions, Pub/Sub, and Cloud Scheduler to run the function on interval.

This guide consists three parts:

1. **Web Scraper**

   1. Build a library consisting your web scraper scripts.
   2. Save your data.
2. **Automation**

   1. On [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/), Navigate to [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions).
   2. Click **Create Function**, a form will appear.
   3. Name the function, set the memory depending on how complex is your web scraping script.
   4. Setup the **Trigger**; This allows to know when will the function trigger.
   5. Choose **Cloud Pub/Sub** as a trigger; This is a mechanism that is used for communicating or triggering between different components in GCP.
   6. Click **Create a Topic**, a popup window will show. Name it and click **Create Topic**.
   7. Select the topic that you previously created.
   8. Click **Next**.
   9. On the **Runtime** dropdown, Choose your Python version.
   10. On the **Source Code** dropdown, You can choose if you would write the code in the **Inline Editor** or you could choose **Zip Upload** to upload your Python Web Scraper Scripts.
   11. Before you upload your Zip archive, make sure to add a “**requirements.txt**” file to the ZIP archive, where you list all the “**pip**” dependencies your function uses.

You may refer [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-starting-cloudfunctions#2) for creating and testing cloud functions.

3. **Triggering the function**

   1. Navigate to [Cloud Scheduler](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler).
   2. Click **Create a Job**.
   3. Name it, Add a description.
   4. For the frequency, you must provide a string in a “**unix-cron**” format. You can refer [here](https://crontab.guru/) for unix-cron time format.
   5. Choose your **Timezone**. Click **Continue**.
   6. On **Configure your Extension**, Select **Pub/Sub** on **Target type** dropdown.
   7. Select your previously created Pub/Sub Topic on **Cloud Pub/Sub topic** dropdown.
   8. On the **Message Body**, it’s used to transfer some data with the triggering of a topic. Put anything you want in here.
   9. Click Create.

You may refer on [Using Pub/Sub to trigger a Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub) for further documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but may i know is it only py file and requirement.txt file only, we need to upload into zip folder?

Comment: Yes and please make sure that all the "pip" dependencies(if you have) are in the "requirements.txt".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloud Run and base your developments on this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/python). You need to keep the webserver (flask), run your code in the context of a request handling.

Then you can schedule your Cloud Run with Cloud Scheduler, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler)